# How to make OpenSSL C server only support TLS 1.3?

Tags: c, server, openssl, tls1.3

We are having a Linux C program making use of OpenSSL APIs, acting as a TLS server. It currently has code as:

```
  context = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_method());
```

Which the OpenSSL v1.1.1 manual page says will support SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3. While we now have a new requirement to only support TLS 1.3. Will setting SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version(TLS1_3_VERSION) just do the trick? Or is there other practical way for the server to reject client connections with version lower than TLS 1.3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version(context, TLS1_3_VERSION);` is all that is needed.  This restricts sessions created from this context to not use versions of TLS below 1.3.

Also, you can use `TLS_server_method` to create a context object that will create sessions that default to server mode.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution similar to the one already posted is to use `SSL_CTX_set_options`
Which allows you to pass all protocols you want to ignore such as

```
SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3, SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1, SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1, SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2
```